# Magento 2 separate read/write database connections

Tags: mysql, magento2

What is the proper way to define separate read and write connections to separate MySQL databases in app/etc/env.php for Magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the key here is to think of the Magento 1.X read write connections as master/slave connections in 2.X. I believe this is an enterprise only feature so community editions users might be out of luck. Below is an excerpt of my app/etc/env.php. We are using haproxy to balance read/write connections to a Percona cluster so unless you have the same setup you will need to configure your hosts to the appropriate IP's.

```
...
'db' =>
    array (
        'connection' =>
            array (
                'default' =>
                    array (
                        // HaProxy Write (master) connection
                        'host' => '127.0.0.1:3308',
                        'port' => '3308',
                        'dbname' => 'magento_db',
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password',
                        'active' => '1',
                    ),

            ),
        'slave_connection' =>
            array (
                'default' =>
                    array (
                        // HaProxy Read (slave) connection
                        'host' => '127.0.0.1:3307',
                        'port' => '3307',
                        'dbname' => 'magento_db',
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password',
                        'active' => '1',
                    ),
            ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
    ),
...
```

Comment: have you tried this setup with Seperate Aurora Read and Write DBs ? Please find link for ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31145